# Selenium tiktok-uploader issues with chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, tiktok

I'm trying to upload to TikTok using the TikTok-uploader package and I can't seem to get it working. The documentation says that chromedriver should be downloaded automatically when I try to run this code:

```
upload_video(f"ViralBear/ready/{filepath}", description= description,  cookies_list =    cookies)
```

However, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

But then when I add the chromedriver myself in this code along with some other options:

```
options = Options() 
options.binary_location = "ViralBear/chromedriver"
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
upload_video(f"ViralBear/ready/{filepath}", description= description, cookies_list =   cookies, options= options)
```

I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to        start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location ViralBear/chromedriver is no longer running, so     ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

If someone would help me out, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

I tried to add the chromedriver, but then it gave me a different error. I have a feeling it might be related to my chromedriver version. My chrome is Version 115.0.5790.114 (Official Build) (arm64), but the one I downloaded is the most recent stable release "115.0.5790.102" for mac arm64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an active bug with the latest chromedriver 115:

- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/issues/30
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1466427#c27
- `ChromeDriver requires a Chrome for Testing binary by default`

To fix, delete your chromedriver `115`, download the latest version of `selenium`, and use this code: (Selenium Manager will give you a working chromedriver, which is currently at `114` until fixed very soon.)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

---

Note that https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following arguments unless they are mandatory:

- *`options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")`*
- *`options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")`*

and execute your test.

Comment: I have tried it without those. I just saw somewhere else online to add those to fix (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)